# If a character has the TWF feat from 3.5 and the Ambidexterity feat from 3.0, does this remove the TWF penalty?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

I'm not exactly sure how these would stack if they were both allowed.  Would the -2/-2 with a light weapon and TWF be eliminated or would it be exactly the same (thus making Ambidexterity obviously redundant)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 3.5 Two Weapon Fighting feat already includes the benefit of 3.0 Ambidexterity.

**3.0 Two Weapon Fighting penalties:**

> If a normal character (i.e. a character without the multiattack and/or multidexterity feats) wields a second weapon (fights two handed), that character can get one extra attack per round with that weapon. Fighting in this way is very hard, however, and the character suffers a -6 penalty for regular attacks with the first hand and a -10 penalty to the attack with a other hand. A character can reduce these stiff penalties in three ways:
>
> - If a character's second weapon is light, the penalties are reduced by 2 each.
> - **The Ambidexterity feat reduces the penalty against the second weapon by 4.**
> - **The Two-Weapon Fighting feat reduces both penalties by 2.**

**3.5 Two Weapon Fighting penalties:**

> If you wield a second weapon in your off hand, you can get one extra attack per round with that weapon. You suffer a -6 penalty with your regular attack or attacks with your primary hand and a -10 penalty to the attack with your off hand when you fight this way. You can reduce these penalties in two ways:
>
> - If your off-hand weapon is light, the penalties are reduced by 2 each. (An unarmed strike is always considered light.)
> - **The Two-Weapon Fighting feat lessens the primary hand penalty by 2, and the off-hand penalty by 6.**

Presented in a table for comparison

```
                 3.0        3.5
               PRI  OFF   PRI  OFF
No feats       -6   -10   -6   -10
Light weapon   -4   -8    -4   -8
+TWF feat      -2   -6    -2   -2
+Ambidex feat  -2   -2    N/A  N/A
```

Ambidexterity (by common English definition) means your off hand is as good as your primary hand. If you tried to reintroduce the 3.0 feat *exactly as written*, then it would make your off hand *better* than your primary hand in 3.5.

If you were to reintroduce Ambidexterity into 3.5, then *the whole of 3.0's two weapon penalty table* should be reintroduced with it - ie, the Two Weapon Fighting feat would be *far less* effective at improving your off-hand attacks.

Answer (score 8):

**They do not stack at all.**

Ambidexterous not appearing in 3.5 is not a case of oversight or cutting content to save space. You have to remember that the entire purpose of 3.5 was to revise a significant number of design defects in 3.0. In 3.0, any character who wanted to take Two-Weapon Fighting was functionally guaranteed to take Ambidexterous, which led to heavy abuse of single-level Rangers. Because of this, the designers opted to roll part of the benefit of Ambidexterous into Two-Weapon Fighting and do away with the first feat entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to introduce ambidexterity back in I would say 2 weapon fighting would be a prerequisite.  It would further decrease the penalties for the weapons by -2/-2 thus nullifying any penalties for using 2 weapons/ 2 handed weapons. 
You only get so many feats in the run of a game (assuming you stop at 20th level).